# Limit [access] to this tag: Burninate or merge with [access-control]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) tag is a tag with 1720 questions, and its description is

> In computer security, general access control includes identification, authentication, authorization, access approval, and audit.
>
> Note: For Microsoft Access questions, use ms-access instead.

It is being misused a lot, mainly for questions that should be posted under [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) (417 questions tagged both [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), 157 questions tagged [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) and [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access), 201 questions tagged [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) and [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba)). While some may be valid (you can ask about access control in Microsoft Access or VBA), in a quick search I haven't found any.

There are even 20 questions tagged both [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) and [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) where both tags are improperly used (referring to the macro functionality in Microsoft Access)

There is further misuse with questions about limiting internet access to programs, access-denied errors (which could be posted under the [access-denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-denied) tag), and accessing various things in various programming languages (offsite resources, global variables and such).

In my opinion, there are two ways to go about this:

1. Burninate the tag.
2. Merge the tag with [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control)

Burninating the tag may be appropriate. There's a lot of misuse, but the tag is on-topic and might add meaningful information. It's a very broad tag, but might mean approximately the same in most common contexts.

If we accept the narrow use of [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) provided in it's description instead of its actual broad usage, we could also merge it with [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control), since its tag description already refers to it as access control. If we make sure [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) is the main tag and [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) is the synonym, this might also avoid a lot of misuse (someone asking about Microsoft Access will surely realize [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) is the wrong tag).

**Note:** there's currently a vote on the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag to mark [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) as a synonym (I didn't even know this was an option for already existing tags). Merging these two is a bad plan, since they mean very different things.

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Comment: It's hard to think of a good question that would need this tag... To begin with, there are too many concept in the tag's description

Comment: How is "access-denied" a useful tag?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Haven't thought about that actually. It might be useful for people running into access-denied errors, but you might argue it adds little to the question, and that would certainly be true

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: We generally don't have a tag for each kind of error one can encounter, there are too many of them. The error will appear in the title/body of the question and be searchable without a specific tag.

Comment: Very true. I'm just pointing out it exists, and is especially made for these questions that are wrongfully tagged [tag:access]

Comment: @MatthieuM. Doesn't "access-denied" refer to people who didn't purchase the Professional version of MS Office?  ;-)

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I’m removing the tag; it’s a manual process right now as there is no burnination support available.

I’m cleaning up the posts where possible; we have a mix of access-control, Microsoft Access and general “trying to access X” questions, after all.

Comment: the tag popped up again yesterday and I retagged a few questions to ms-access but since then another two questions came up, one ms-access and one OT general hard/software. Retagged both, but it will certainly not solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Suggestion: Most of the questions belong to [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access). The others should be checked, renamed, and *then* [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) should either be made a synonym to [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) or [banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61822/ban-programming-as-a-tag-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: Change it to just banned to get an upvote.

Answer (score -3):

I wholeheartedly agree that issues surrounding the [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) tag need to be addressed in some way, however, given that:

1. The main reason for the misuse of this tag is the incorrect tagging of [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) questions.
2. There exists the single-word tags [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook) for other MS Office applications.
3. Most users refer to MS Access simply as 'Access' and are too lazy to read the tag descriptions.
4. The current incarnation of the [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) covers such a broad and vague subject area, applicable to any programming language and a multitude of fields (access to files, networks, accounts etc.), rendering it useless for anyone searching for questions on this topic.

Would it not be more appropriate to reassign this tag as a synonym of the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag?