# Frequent misuse of tag [spark-java]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

I have subscribed to [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java) on SO specifically to be able to see and answer to new questions on the Spark Web Framework, a.k.a http://sparkjava.com/ - not Apache Spark a.k.a http://spark.apache.org/

However many, if not most, questions that land into my inbox with this tag are related to [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) instead. It looks like people interested in Apache Spark with Java end up erroneously adding [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java).

How would it be possible to avoid this? I'm tempted to add "NOT related to apache-spark" in the tag's description, or maybe to rename it to sparkjava (without the hyphen), but neither option completely convinces me.

Comment: Welcome to the party, pal. No one reads the tag usage (i.e. excerpt). I spend a goodly portion of my time on SO removing the tag `model-view-controller` from questions about the ASP.NET MVC framework because `mvc` is a synonym of `model-view-controller`...

Comment: And then we have the questions about _both_ [apache-spark] and [spark-java].

Comment: It seems to be time that one of these two projects changes their name… The actual name of spark-java is actually just [_Spark_](https://github.com/perwendel/spark). I suppose they chose sparkjava.com because spark.com was already taken.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan isn't ASP.NET MVC a `model-view-controller` oriented framework though? If not, the Wikipedia article is in dire need of fixing.

Comment: @mbrig, sure, but questions about, say, Adding a route to ASP.NET MVC 4 has nothing to do with the *pattern* MVC, which is what the `model-view-controller` tag is supposed to be used for.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah I see. I guess I had assumed that would be obvious... that will teach me to assume anything.

Comment: @mbrig It doesn't help that someone who's typing `asp.net mvc` into the tags ends up with `asp.net` `model-view-controller`.

Answer (score 16):

Rename it to [spark-web-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-web-framework) to hint this isn't the same thing as Apache Spark.

Comment: Yes my first thought. Why call the tag for a web framework spark-*java*?  You're bound to get questions on that tag for whatever java framework that is called "spark" is currently the most popular.

Comment: I agree. Then burninate [`spark-framework`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework)? I'm sure it suffers from the same issue... see the tag wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Good point.

The text **`DO NOT USE FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT APACHE SPARK.`** [has been added to the tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19006854). Let's see if it helps.

You can propose these tag changes yourself.

Comment: My experience with such an excerpt (on the [tag:access] tag) is that it does very little. But we can hope.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: maybe that tag should be renamed access-control (the tag wiki has that use and it even reads unnatural to have `access` tagged and *control* untagged)

Comment: yup, it's an awful tag, that's why I posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356097/7296893) burninate/merge request last september. I especially dislike the questions tagged both [tag:access] and [tag:denied]...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth sometimes we write the book only so we can throw it at people

Comment: This **will not work**. You can compare already existing tags that have these warnings. E.g. `angularjs` (which has "_Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2_") and `angular` (used for versions 2/4/5+). People just assume they are the same and tag with the wrong one or even both, _because others will fix these tags for them anyway_

Answer (score 1):

The rename to [sparkjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparkjava), while perhaps feeling a little silly, would be a lot more likely to bear fruitful results. Since Apache Spark is built on Scala/Java, people are going to be asking questions with "Spark-Java" on their brains, and I don't really blame them.

As has been noted, a note on the tag excerpt is a weak option, whereas two tags would (hopefully) force people to stop and choose the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Rename to `sparkjava-web` to make it more clear, no one reads tag usage and description.