# Disambiguate [Token]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Tag info for [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token):

> A token is a string of characters, categorized according to the rules
>   as a symbol (e.g., IDENTIFIER, NUMBER, COMMA). The process of forming
>   tokens from an input stream of characters is called tokenization, and
>   the lexer categorizes them according to a symbol type. A token can
>   look like anything that is useful for processing an input text stream
>   or text file.

There are ~4,600 questions. Of the first 50, about 8 have to do with tokens in the sense of tokenization. The others have to do with authentication tokens.

The questions related to tokenization should be retagged to [tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tokenize). For the other usage, [access-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-token) exists, but I don't have enough experience in that domain to say if it's a good target. Perhaps [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token) ought to be renamed to something more specific.

Comment: The [Token] is Invalid?

Answer (score 4):

[access-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-token) is certainly not a good target, since it's about a specific token you get during the OAuth process (additionally to [refresh-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refresh-token)). Many of these questions are related to some form of HTTP based authentication, so perhaps [http-token-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-token-authentication) could be a good target for many of them, or a new tag ([authentication-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication-token), [security-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security-token), ...) should be created.

Here are some "types" of questions I noticed within [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token):

- [About 300 of those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token+jwt) are also tagged [jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt), and are about JSON Web Tokens.
- Another about ~400 questions are either about [access-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-token), [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth) or [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0), which are all related to the OAuth rpocess.
- Additionally to that, there are also [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access+token) tagged both [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) and [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token), these should be tagged [access-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-token) in stead. (Related: [Burnination of the access tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356097/limit-access-to-this-tag-burninate-or-merge-with-access-control))
- There are also a few questions about ["bad tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bad%20token%22%20%5Btoken%5D&mixed=1), ["invalid tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22invalid%20token%22%20%5Btoken%5D&mixed=1) or ["unexpected tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btoken%5D+%22unexpected%22&mixed=1) which have nothing to do about authentication tokens. I don't know if we really need a tag for those, since that tag would still be really broad.
- As you mentioned, [many of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btoken%5D%20%22tokenize%22&mixed=0) are also about String tokenization. Some of them are already tagged [tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tokenize), but in other occasions it is being tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) or [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing).
- There is also the combination [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device)  and [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token), which should probably become [devicetoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devicetoken) in stead.
- The combination [csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csrf) and [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token) also pops up sometimes. No clue what should happen with those. If they're related to Ruby, they could perhaps be tagged with [authenticicity-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authenticicity-token) in stead? Seems the CSRF is another mess though, since some are tagged [csrf-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csrf-protection) in stead.
- Another combination I see pop up sometimes is [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) and [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token), but that's still fairly broad, as some are about adding the CSRF token to the form, some aren't.

From the [remaining questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token+-jwt+-refresh-token+-access-token+-oauth+-oauth-2.0+-access+-forms+-device+-string+-parsing+-csrf-protection+-regex+-syntax), many are about custom tokens, or specific tokens generated by some frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be an expert in tokens? It's not likely; the term is far too broad. An access token is not comparable to a token in a lexical parser, which is not comparable to a CSRF token. I don't think there's value in this meta-tag.

It seems more plausible to be an expert at `tokenization`, since the algorithms once might apply are language-independent; I know a few people that love writing parsers.

However, the vast majority of the questions tagged with `token` are about access tokens, particularly the `jwt` variety. In most cases, we could just remove the `token` tag and nothing of value would be lost.